# Node.js (npm) refuses to find python even after %PYTHON% has been set

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, npm

So I am trying to get the Node.js to work. Of course, it's not as easy as advertised :)

I happen to have two python versions on my computer, but Node.js seems to only work with the older one, 2.7. Upon error, it also encourages me to set the path into `PYTHON` environment variable with this error:

```
Error: Can't find Python executable "python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
```

Ok then, I configured the variable as desired:

```
C:\Users\Jakub>set PYTHON=C:\MYSELF\Programs\Python2.7\python.exe

C:\Users\Jakub>echo %PYTHON%
C:\MYSELF\Programs\Python2.7\python.exe
```

You can see that I used `echo` to check whether the variable was really set. Unfortunatelly, that `npm` thing can't read it and the error appears again. Here's the full log right after I set the `%PYTHON%` variable:

```
C:\Users\Jakub>npm install minecraft-protocol
\


> ursa@0.8.5 install C:\Users\Jakub\node_modules\minecraft-protocol\node_modules\ursa
> node-gyp rebuild

|
C:\Users\Jakub\node_modules\minecraft-protocol\node_modules\ursa>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\no
de_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (rebuild)
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:64:11
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (evalmachine.<anonymous>:95:15)
```

Comment: Changes to environment variables using "set" only last for the duration of the cmd window.

Comment: I didn't close the window - the `npm install ...` was issued right after configuring the variable, in the same window.

Comment: I had a similar issue on Windows 10. I ended up uninstalling Node, Python, Electron, and NPM, restarting my computer, reinstalling Node, Python, Electron, and NPM, then restarting my computer again before it finally worked.

gyp + windows = joke

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I figured out the most stable solution is to set `python` npm internal value to actual path:

```
npm config set python C:\Programs\Python2.7\python2.7.exe
```

This skips all environment variable and `%PATH%` crap and just starts the python wherever it's installed.

Comment: Setting the environment variables didn't work for me either. This answer did! Thanks

Comment: Also make sure that you have the correct version installed!

Comment: I had to specifically add both `python` and `PYTHON` to my config before gyp would run.

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR  Make a copy or alias of your python.exe with name python2.7.exe**

My python 2.7 was installed as

```
D:\app\Python27\python.exe
```

I always got this error no matter how I set (and verified) PYTHON env variable:

```
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:103:14)
```

The reason for this was that in node-gyp's configure.js the python executable was resolved like:

`var python = gyp.opts.python || process.env.PYTHON || 'python'`

And it turned out that gyp.opts.python had value 'python2.7' thus overriding process.env.PYTHON.

I resolved this by creating an alias for python.exe executable with name node-gyp was looking for:

`D:\app\Python27>mklink python2.7.exe python.exe`

You need admin rights for this operation.

Comment: had the same approach but that didn't solve the problem for me.

Comment: @DoubleU23, I recommend using npm config as [Tomáš Zato](http://stackoverflow.com/users/607407/tom%c3%a1%c5%a1-zato) suggested. That seems like the official way. My suggestion is more a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Reopen your terminal after you set your environment variable in case of windows but in case of linux no need to restart terminal.

Comment: Is this meant to be an answer or a comment? Anyway, why do I need to restart terminal (didn't work)?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
npm config set python C:\Users\<username>\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe
```

Set the path to python executable accordingly.
Hope this help :-)

Comment: working for me also... Thanks for the detail info (y)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows goto directory `C:\Users\<<your username>>\.windows-build-tools\python27` and copy and paste the `python.exe` as `python.2.7.exe` in the same directory.

Comment: THIS IS THE SOLUTION!!! a small error, just modify to python2.7.exe, no extra .

Answer (score 1):

I tried everything but none worked for me, then I installed python using this [Link](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2710/) at this location C:\Python27\python.exe

Answer (score 0):

It was admin vs local user issue for me !

Please see my steps in different thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77010764/4099837)