# npm install error with docker - kurento application

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, kurento

I am trying to install a kurento webserver in docker container.

And trying to execute the kurento one to one call tutorial.

I am getting a error during the step npm install.

**Step:**

RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && npm install

**Error is as follows:**

```
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:401:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:330:11
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:63:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:72:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:81:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-32-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call/node_modules/ws/node_modules/utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.46
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Some one help me with the same.

**Docker file is as follows:**

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER USER1 "muraliselva.10@gmail.com"
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install git -y
RUN apt-get install curl -y
RUN echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
RUN wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0 -y
RUN sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
RUN sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 stop
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -
RUN sudo apt-get install -y nodejs -y
RUN sudo npm install -g bower -y
RUN git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-node.git
RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && pwd
RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && git checkout 6.5.0
RUN sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start
RUN cd kurento-tutorial-node/kurento-one2one-call && npm install
EXPOSE 8443
```

Some one help me with fixing the error.

Comment: Did you already try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33047257/3794110)?

Comment: It seems to be a solution for windows .. Here it is Ubuntu ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node version in standard Ubuntu 14.04 packages is pretty old (0.10). Use the installation instructions from the nodejs [web page](https://nodejs.org/es/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions) instead.

You can also choose to build your container FROM a [node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/), and then install Kurento and the kurento one-to-one tutorial on top of that. However, take into account that running several processes within a container can be cumbersome and error prone. Specially when some of the processes are run as services. There are instructions on the official Docker documentation on how to achieve that using Supervisor.