# Not able to run node-gyp rebuild

Tags: python, node.js, express

i wanted to run node-gyp rebuild and i have installed pythod but after doing all steps its give error "can not find python env variable"

[Error which am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2weaW.png)

[Environment variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qLPp.png)

Answer (score 0):

From, the error message it looks that the path you have specified is wrong. Crosscheck once again.

Find more help regarding this in the below link:

[Node.js (npm) refuses to find python even after %PYTHON% has been set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251367/node-js-npm-refuses-to-find-python-even-after-python-has-been-set)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution,Its is coz i installed python-3.6.0 version which was not supported so i uninstall that and installed python 2.7.12 now wokring fine.